# Almost automatically sorting keys with `jq`, but keep "id" key, if present, on top

Tags: json, jq

Is there a way to sort the keys of a JSON using `jq` but keeping keys named "id" as first descendants on all trees? It's nice to have a way to easily compare JSON files to one another and normalizing key order and formatting is a great way to ensure they are easy to match, but sometimes the "id" key is the one we are looking for and it's not always easy to find if it's buried in the middle of the tree.

As an example, this:

```
{
    "z-displacement": 3,
    "absorption": 0.4,
    "collections": [
        {
            "b": 12,
            "a": 18,
            "id" 190:,
        },
        {
            "m": 22,
            "id": 169,
            "n": 3,
        },
    ],
    "id": 256767
}
```

Would become something like:

```
{
    "id": 256767,
    "absorption": 0.4,
    "collections": [
        {
            "id" 190:,
            "a": 18,
            "b": 12
        },
        {
            "id": 169,
            "m": 22,
            "n": 3
        }
    ],
    "z-displacement": 3
}
```

Comment: what is the benefit? it makes no difference when accessing an object key with `.id`

Comment: The benefit is keeping all JSON files consistent, even if changed by a tool that shuffles the keys. A different key order has no semantic meaning, but version control still interprets it as a change.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using jq 1.4 or later, the following will do what is requested for all the JSON objects in the input, not only those at the top level:

```
def reorder:
  (if has("id") then {id} else null end) + (to_entries | sort | from_entries );

walk(if type == "object" then reorder else . end)
```

If your jq does not have `walk/1`, you can snarf its def from the jq FAQ https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ or from the "master" version of [builtin.jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq)

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea how robust this is, but it gets the desired result in this case.

```
jq -S '.' | jq '{id} + .'
```

Comment: I would assume that it is an implementation detail that the keys in `a` appear first in `a + b`, not something that is guaranteed.

Comment: This solution will work for the top-level object (assuming a sufficiently recent version of jq), but it will add an "id" key if there is none, which may not be desired.